# Drupal 7 - Views.css and CTools.css not loaded

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

When using the Views admin panel, it appears completely mispresented. Looking at the files being accessed, it turns out that the needed css files are not loaded. My Drupal installation is within a */drupal/* subfolder, and when the module is trying to access `domain.com/sites/all/modules/views/css/views.css` a 404 is received.
I tried browsing manually to `domain.com/drupal/sites/all/modules/views/css/views.css` and it works, therefore the file is there and can be accessed from the web.

The strange thing is that for other folders there is no problem, for example both `domain.com/modules/user/user.css` and `domain.com/drupal/modules/user/user.css` work. It seems like a problem with *sites/* only...

I do not have CSS optimization enabled, and all folders within *sites/* have a 755 permission. Is there some configuration setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the domain I'm concerned about is a parked domain (or whatever this is called) for another one, and contained in a subfolder of public_html. Drupal installation, thus, is a subfolder of that subfolder (say, /home/user/public_html/my_domain/drupal) and all requests for my domain are redirected via an `.htaccess` and MOD_REWRITE, to the Drupal subfolder. For some reason, it didn't have the *sites/* in its regexp (*modules/* and *themes/* were...).

Answer (score 0):

You may have incorrect vhost configuration. In order to check if this is the reason, try accessing the site without the vhost i.e. `localhost/drupal` and see if this works. 
If it loads correctly, then you need to set up the correct document root:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /www/drupal
 ServerName domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Then restart apache.
For more information about how to set up vhost, visit http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: You're right - the server was misconfigured; however, this was not a problem in vhost but in the `.htaccess`. Apparently there was one up in the directory tree with MOD_REWRITE instructions (and it didn't have _sites/_ in the regexp for some reason). Thanks, you reply guided me to search in the place I haven't thought about.